# show pincode screen on app resume from memory [Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.]

Tags: dart, flutter, onresume

I want to show PinCode on app resume for all loggedIn Users

so i checked that there is WidgetsBindingObserver

and used it like this :

```
class ClientApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ClientAppState createState() => ClientAppState();
}

class ClientAppState extends State<ClientApp>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  @override
  Future didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed &&
        await auth.isLoggedIn() == true) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => PinCode(),
        ),
      );
    }
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

the problem here that if user places app in memory and get in back (onResume) the event triggers right but i get this error

> E/flutter (22097): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)]
>   Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that
>   does not include a Navigator. 
>   E/flutter (22097): The context used to
>   push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is
>   a descendant of a Navigator widget.

that means that user are not in current state as what i think/understand (correct me if i'm wrong) but how is that ?

yea user is somewhere is application ,, even in splash screen ,, but the same error

Answer (score 0):

Using [`natigator Key`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp/navigatorKey.html) might help you to push new route instead of build context.

```
class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: new Center(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now in the method

```
 @override
  Future didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed &&
        await auth.isLoggedIn() == true) {
      Navigator.push(navigatorKey.currentContext,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => PinCode(),
        ),
      );
    }
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
  }
```

This might help to navigate new page after resuming the app.

Comment: have you tested it ? ,, it's throwing the same error

Comment: Oh sorry for that I haven't tested that out.. but usually navigation key is used for the context related issues. I'll check it out once I'm free.